How to carousal proper date wise select data set prev or next button?
{
    "data": [
        {
            "press_id": "1",
            "data11": [
                {
                    "news_id": "9",
                    "image": "/26_327028192291471811.jpg",
                    "title": "Daman Boat Parking Area Development",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                },
                {
                    "news_id": "8",
                    "image": "/21_175883836182750584.jpg",
                    "title": "Visit to Riverfront Park at Duffnala",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                },
               
            ],
            "cover_image": "/23_29_8524647402534314.jpg",
            "from_dt": "23-09-2024",
            "to_dt": "29-09-2024"
        },
        {
            "press_id": "2",
            "data11": [
                {
                    "news_id": "11",
                    "image": "/21_7878627309344664.jpg",
                    "title": "Gandhi Ashram - Site Assessment Visit",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                },
                {
                    "news_id": "12",
                    "image": "/27_0886059029498614.jpg",
                    "title": "The Beatles Ashram, Rishikesh",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                },
             
            ],
            "cover_image": "/22_9252375416640387.jpg",
            "from_dt": "30-09-2024",
            "to_dt": "06-10-2024"
        },
        {
            "press_id": "3",
            "data11": [
                {
                    "news_id": "20",
                    "image": "/1.jpg",
                    "title": "Pawana and Indrayani River Rejuvenation, Pimpri Chinchwad",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                },
                {
                    "news_id": "27",
                    "image": "/8.jpg",
                    "title": "Apollo Flyover, Gandhinagar",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                }
            ],
            "cover_image": "/22_9719651855870003.jpg",
            "from_dt": "07-10-2024",
            "to_dt": "13-10-2024"
        },
        {
            "press_id": "4",
            "data11": [
                {
                    "news_id": "32",
                    "image": "/32.jpg",
                    "title": "Jay Chemical Corporate House, Ahmedabad",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                },
               
            ],
            "cover_image": "/31.jpg",
            "from_dt": "14-10-2024",
            "to_dt": "20-10-2024"
        },
        {
            "press_id": "5",
            "data11": [
                {
                    "news_id": "43",
                    "image": "/43_1947710417459452.jpg",
                    "title": "Beatles Ashram, Rishikesh",
                    "description": "",
                    "layout": "0"
                },
               
            ],
            "cover_image": "/41.jpg",
            "from_dt": "21-10-2024",
            "to_dt": "27-10-2024"
        }
    ]
}
 updateFilteredPressData() {
    if (this.selectedDate) {
      const selectedDate = new Date(this.selectedDate);
      selectedDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      const selectedDateData: any[] = [];
      const futureData: any[] = [];
      const pastData: any[] = [];
      this.pressLayouts.forEach((layout: any) => {
        const fromDate = new Date(
          layout.from_dt.split('-').reverse().join('-')
        );
        const toDate = new Date(layout.to_dt.split('-').reverse().join('-'));
        fromDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        toDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (selectedDate >= fromDate && selectedDate <= toDate) {
          selectedDateData.push(layout);
        } else if (selectedDate < fromDate) {
          futureData.push(layout);
        } else {
          pastData.push(layout);
        }
      });
      futureData.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        const dateA = new Date(
          a.from_dt.split('-').reverse().join('-')
        ).getTime();
        const dateB = new Date(
          b.from_dt.split('-').reverse().join('-')
        ).getTime();
        return dateA - dateB;
      });
      pastData.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        const dateA = new Date(
          a.from_dt.split('-').reverse().join('-')
        ).getTime();
        const dateB = new Date(
          b.from_dt.split('-').reverse().join('-')
        ).getTime();
        return dateB - dateA;
      });
      this.filteredPressData = [
        ...selectedDateData,
        ...futureData,
        ...pastData,
      ];
      this.activeIndex = 0;
      console.log('Filtered Data:', this.filteredPressData);

      this.currentPressData =
        this.filteredPressData.length > 0
          ? this.filteredPressData[0].data11 || []
          : [];
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    } else {
      this.filteredPressData = this.pressLayouts;
      this.currentPressData =
        this.filteredPressData.length > 0
          ? this.filteredPressData[0].data11 || []
          : [];
    }
  }
  updateCurrentPressData(index: any) {
    if (this.filteredPressData[index.page]) {
      this.selectedDate = null;
      this.currentPressData = this.filteredPressData[index.page].data11 || [];
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    } else {
      this.currentPressData = [];
    }

  onDateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    if (event.value) {
      this.selectedDate = event.value;
      this.updateFilteredPressData();
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    } else {
      this.selectedDate = null;
      this.filteredPressData = this.pressLayouts;
      this.currentPressData =
        this.filteredPressData.length > 0
          ? this.filteredPressData[0].data11 || []
          : [];
    }
  }

when i first visit the press page and directly select a date the data is set fine but when i visit the pae and click the slider button and go to prev or next and then select a date the data is not set properly
for example i select date from_date to to_dt between date 30-09-2024 then this date come first and data set to this date to next week date 07-10-2024 to 13-10-2024,14-10-2024 to 20-10-2024,21-10-2024 to 27-10-2024 and last data set to 23-09-2024 to 29-09-2024 this just for example for undestanding
so, how can solutions carousal primeng in angualr
date wise select data set `

It's not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to store the selection an user made? If so, what have you've tried? Where are you stuck? How is the posted snippet related to the issue - Please have a look at [ask]
